# How to run a java application with jshell?

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

How to run a java application with jshell? It should be able to specify classpath and call java command and pass some arguments like bash does,e.g,

```
#!/bin/bash
$ARGS=...
$CLASSPATH=...
java -cp $CLASSPATH $ARGS com.example.MyApp
```

**Update:**
I think a wrapper of Runtime or Process is required, e.g.,

```
jshell> private String executeCommand(String command) {
   ...>
   ...>         StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
   ...>
   ...>         Process p;
   ...>         try {
   ...>             p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
   ...>             p.waitFor();
   ...>             BufferedReader reader =
   ...>                             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
   ...>
   ...>                         String line = "";
   ...>             while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
   ...>                 output.append(line + "\n");
   ...>             }
   ...>
   ...>         } catch (Exception e) {
   ...>             e.printStackTrace();
   ...>         }
   ...>
   ...>         return output.toString();
   ...>
   ...>     }
|  Created method executeCommand(String)

jshell> String out =executeCommand("java --version");
out ==> "java 9.0.4\nJava(TM) SE Runtime Environment (bui ... d 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)\n"

jshell> System.out.println(out);
java 9.0.4
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: are you looking for a way for compiling java from jshell ?

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to call normal "commands" like `java` or `ls` etc from jshell.

Comment: there's a jshell plugin for gradle, if you're looking to build java projects with jshell.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is broken, as you are waiting for the command’s completion first and only afterwards reading the pipe. If the command produces more output than the pipe can buffer, the command will get blocked and never complete, as no-one is reading the pipe at this point.

In a perfect world, you would just use

```
new ProcessBuilder(your command and args).inheritIO().start().waitFor()
```

as in a normal Java application. Unfortunately, `jshell` changes the standard file descriptors in a way that this doesn't work (at least in the Windows version I tested).

You can use

```
void run(String... arg) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  Path tmp = Files.createTempFile("run", ".tmp");
  try {
    new ProcessBuilder(arg).redirectErrorStream(true).redirectOutput(tmp.toFile())
      .start().waitFor();
    Files.lines(tmp, java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset())
      .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
  finally { Files.delete(tmp); }
}
```

and call it like, e.g.

```
run("java", "-version")
```

or

```
run("java", "-d", "java.base")
```

Comment: Works fine on MacOS as well. (Y)

Answer (score 3):

For Running any application in jshell first set the classpath to the jshell at the starting.

Example:

```
jshell -class-path /Users/sree/Desktop/libs/jettison-1.0.1.jar
```

Then import the class into the environment running

```
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
```

This will import the required class into the environment.

Now run the required application. In my case, I entered

```
String myString = new JSONObject().put("JSON", "Hello, World!").toString()
```

And got back the output

```
myString ==> "{\"JSON\":\"Hello, World!\"}"
```

answering the question for passing command line arguments. you have to initiate the class with all the values.

```
Test instance = new Test("data","data1")
```