# Using JShell to write application extensions

Tags: beanshell, jshell

at the moment I use Beanshell to write application extensions. I just use BshMethod.invoke() to integrate it with the java application.

Could this be done with JShell too? Load a script and execute a method in the script? Via a JShell API, not via cmdline...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a java application with jshell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072972/how-to-run-a-java-application-with-jshell)

Comment: No - i do not want to call os cmds from jshell nor do I want to call a java api from a jshell cmdline.

Comment: I used a *.jsh file to startup jshell. See the [Symbolic Math Scripting With JShell example](https://dzone.com/articles/jshell-symbolic-math-scripting)